# Is there support for country-select gem in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error in Rails 5. When I click create new user button via ActiveAdmin and it throws this error, FYI, User table has the field 'country' and i have used, gem 'country-select' in my Gemfile.

```
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved it by changing the gem. I replaced `gem 'country-select'` with `gem 'country_select'` in my Gemfile.

This works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `country_select` providing support for rails5. I installed rails5 and executed the test suite and all spec are passing.

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 45263
...................

Finished in 1.87 seconds (files took 0.94449 seconds to load)
19 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 45263
```

May be your syntax is wrong [usage](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#usage)

Comment: Thanks for the response & Hint @ABPrime